# How to draw multiple vectors defined with arrays of coordinates in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, vector, plot

I'm new in Python and i need some help. This is the issue:

I extracted some point sources from an image with two different algorithms. Since 
points are the same, image coordinates of the points should be same, but algorithms works with different functions so values are close but not exactly the same. Now i need to draw vectors in the same graph with the size of the image to show the difference.

I have four arrays. Two holds the x,y coordinates of points found with the first algorithm separately (np.x1, np.y1) and the other two holds the x,y values found with the second algorithm (np.x2, np.y2).

Vectors should begin from the x1,y1 coordinates and go to x2,y2 coordinates. I can draw just one vector (from np.x1[0],np.y1[0] to np.x2[0],np.y2[0]) with this codes:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.x1=[1189.01,1185.0,1012.163,1873.221,194.2559]
np.y1=[14.45688,979.85659999999996,639.15629999999,249.173599999,67.10436]
np.x2=[1188.8416489474798,1184.843265982,1012.074063414,1873.077105230,194.30567379144]
np.y2=[14.855950959,980.058587129,639.232680302,249.412057655,67.3004825209]
soa = np.array([[np.x1[0]],[np.y1[0]],[np.x2[0]], np.y2[0]])
X, Y, U, V = zip(soa)
plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
ax.quiver(X, Y, U, V, angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=10,)
ax.set_xlim([0, 1472])
ax.set_ylim([0, 2184])
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

And with a "while" loop, i can draw different graphs, but how can i plot all the vectors in the same graph? Or can you suggest a more efficient way to do this?

Note that points x1[i],y1[i] and x2[i],y2[i] are the same.

Comment: Can you please edit your code example so that it works? People are more likely to help you if they can simply copy/paste the code and run it.

Comment: Thanks for noticing @kazemakase . I added the variables of the coordinates. If any other errors please let me know.

Comment: Also editted a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note syntax of plt.quiver(X, Y, U, V):

X and Y are the coordinates where drawn vectors start. U and V are directions of vectors in X and Y direction.
If you give a list (or 1D numpy array) of values for each, you can draw multiple vectors at once.

It should work like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.x1=np.array([1189.01,1185.0,1012.163,1873.221,194.2559])
np.y1=np.array([14.45688,979.85659999999996,639.15629999999,249.173599999,67.10436])
np.x2=np.array([1188.8416489474798,1184.843265982,1012.074063414,1873.077105230,194.30567379144])
np.y2=np.array([14.855950959,980.058587129,639.232680302,249.412057655,67.3004825209])
plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
ax.quiver(np.x1, np.y1, np.x2-np.x1, np.y2-np.y1, angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=10)
ax.set_xlim([0, 1472])
ax.set_ylim([0, 2184])
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

Note that your vectors are very short compared to the distance of their origins, so you likely will not see arrows in your plots but just points.

Comment: Thank you @Stefan. That solved my problem. I also realized that my variables were not arrays but dictionaries. That's why i tried many example codes but they didn't work.